# How to decrease embedded video height using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an embedded video in my page. My problem is my embedded video size is to large. The width is fine. But the height is to large. How can I control the height of my video?

Here's my code:

```
<div id="video-banner" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video controls loop class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="public/videos/intramart.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 // NO EFFECT
    #video-banner {
        height: 150px;
    }
```

Comment: try putting !important rule and see if it will change, if it changed then there is an existing height property and it is what it follows.

"The !important rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document."

Comment: Ok I will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just give height in `<video>` tag. You can specify the height and width of the embedded video using this. do as follows

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls loop class="embed-responsive-item">
    <source src="public/videos/intramart.mp4" type=video/mp4>
</video>
```